# jquery - Multi-line textbox

Tags: jquery

My first time here, and sorry for my bad English

Need to let user write some text in my page and i guess multiline textbox is what i going to use. However, i can only send a 256 long field to the server (limits in the tool we are using), so i need some help

I need to populate the textbox with 1-10? fields (256) length when page is loaded
I need to extract the data, line by line, from textbox and put it in my fields when user press save button

Spent some hours on the internet but can't find what i'm looking for

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Can you post HTML for reference? It seems like it had nothing to do with jquery, and in HTML instead of textbox, you should be using textarea.

Comment: Hi, I have not done this yet, my thought was that i could use jquery to put together a number of fields in a textbox and then divide them into fields before I send it to the server. The problem is that i can only send a field with maxlenght 256 and the field where we save the data is 2640

Comment: as posted in one of the answer you can specify maxlength at input control level so you don't need jquery to do that check.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the length of that text input.

```
<textarea maxlength="256" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that we have a field with length 2640 and we can only send 256. So  i need 10 fields into my function and put it in a textbox, and of course split it in to 10 fields to send i to server, where we put them together again.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually what I do on `submit` - getting the content from a `textArea`

```
var comment = $("#comment").val();
if (comment.length >= 256) {
alert ("comment is too long");
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
}
```